# How to find out the coefficient in matching pursuit algorithm

Tags: matlab, dictionary, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to implement Matching Pursuit algorithm in Matlab.I have found out the maximum inner product value ,i m stuck with how to find out the coeffients.
help me out.
Here is the algorithm

```
D=[1 6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46
   2 7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42 47
   3 8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48
   4 9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49
   5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50];
b=[16;17;18;19;20];
n=size(D);
A1=zeros(n);
R=b;
x=[];
H=10;
if(H <= 0)
error('The number of iterations needs to be greater then 0')
end;   
[c,d] = max(abs(D'*R));
```

Here i have used a prefined dictionary.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function based on "S. Mallat, Z. Zhang, 1993. Matching pursuit in a time frequency dictionary. IEEE Transactions Signal Processing, Vol. 41, No. 12, pp. 3397-3415."

x = MP(b,D,10);

```
function S = MP(y,Dictionary,iteration)
n = size(Dictionary,2);
S = zeros(n,1);
% Normalize the dictionary atoms (coloumns) to have unit norm
% It's better to implement this part out of function, 
% to normalize the dictionary just one time!
%************************************** 
for j = 1:n;
    Dictionary(:,j) = Dictionary(:,j)/norm(Dictionary(:,j));
end 
% *************************************

for i = 1:iteration
    gn = Dictionary' * y / norm(y);
    [MAX,index] = max(abs(gn));
    y = y - MAX * Dictionary(:,index);
    S(index) = MAX + S(index);
end
```

Comment: >> x=MP(b,D,10)

x =

     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0